# Changing default ORDER BY from ASC to DESC globally for all queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

So laravel eloquent is using `id asc` as default in every query ... which is a big problem for me because in most cases i need data to be sorted by `id desc`

And i dont think its just me ... you almost always want new rows to show in the top of the list in the view .

Whether its list of news or users or a blog posts  .

Of curse i can use `->orderBy('id' , 'desc')` but if i have to write this for every single query i think i would need to see a shrink after each project !

So i'm looking for a clean way and  without a need to add something to each model ... apparently there is `Global Scopes` but i need to add id to each model which i'm ging to consider it as plan B .

So , im looking to change this globally for each and every query ... is there a way or should i go with plan B!?

Comment: You should go plan B

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701216/laravel-default-orderby

Comment: @JesúsAmieiro thanx , i've seen this , it suggest using global scope which i've coverd in my question

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can change Laravels default orderBy

```
/**
 * Add an "order by" clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  string  $direction
 * @return $this
 */
public function orderBy($column, $direction = 'asc')
{
    $this->{$this->unions ? 'unionOrders' : 'orders'}[] = [
        'column' => $column,
        'direction' => strtolower($direction) == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc',
    ];
    return $this;
}
```

In /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php

Change:

```
public function orderBy($column, $direction = 'asc')
```

to:

```
public function orderBy($column, $direction = 'desc')
```

@Grzegorz Gajda is correct though, you shouldn't edit Laravel Code.  Best solution is to use Laravel as it was designed, when you want descending:

```
->orderBy('id' , 'desc');
```

Comment: You shouldn't edit external dependencies especially Laravel code. What happen when somebody would want to update Laravel to newer version?

Comment: @cmac as you said it's not right to edit laravel code , but in the other hand this is what i want since apparently there is no out of box solution

Comment: @max long as you are aware of the implications and don't forget if you ever update laravel, etc, etc...  Glad I could help you.  If this answer solves your problem please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose you can use a custom `BaseClass` which will define the default `orderBy` property to desc and then you can Extend your Models to this class  instead of `Model` class.

Custom BaseClass:

```
class BaseClass extends Model{
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope('order', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->orderBy($builder->column,'desc');
    });
  }
}
```

Then all the Models where you want to achieve order by `desc`, extend it with this `BaseClass`:
Your Model:

```
class abcModel extends BaseModel{
//Your code
}
```

To remove the default behavior just use:

```
abcModel::withoutGlobalScope('order')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just simply make your own query function and have it call `->orderBy('id' , 'desc')`? I can't think of any other solution.