# Eloquent Relationships in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relational-database, relationship, laravel-5.5

i have three table as follows:

```
users:
id, fullname, phone ... 

tasks: 
id, user_id, title, description ...

tasks_state:
id, task_id, comment, rating, createa_at, updated_at
```

i am trying to use Relationships in laravel for order by `updated_at` in table `tasks_state`

```
Model tasks 

public function taskstate()
{
    return $this->hasOne(TaskState::class, 'task_id');
}

Model tasks_state

public function task()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tasks::class, 'id', 'taks_id');
}
```

I want the data returned sorted by field `updated_at` in table `tasks_state` when i use:

```
Tasks:with('taskstate')->get();
```

Look forward to your help :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent sort by relation table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530051/laravel-eloquent-sort-by-relation-table-column)

Answer (score 2):

Change your Task Model like this:

Model tasks

```
public function taskstate()
{
    return $this->hasOne(TaskState::class, 'task_id')->orderBy('tasks_state.updated_at');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use query builder within with clause and order the task state by **updated_at**

```
Tasks:with([
           'taskstate' => function($query){
               $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');}
])->get();
```

If you want to retrieve everytime with updated_at in desc order, you can reference to [Stack Overflow: Laravel default orderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701216/laravel-default-orderby?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks for you @Hunterrr